# 8 ball Pool: Left only with black ball

Tags: pool

What happens if I have only the 8 (black) ball left to pot and my opponent who has a colored ball scratches the cue ball? Do I get a ball in hand or do I have to try potting the black ball from behind 'the line'?

Answer (score 3):

It depends what rules you play by.  By Official pool rules, you would have ball in hand as they committed a foul.

> **3.9 Standard Fouls**
>
> If the shooter commits a foul, play passes to his opponent. The cue ball is in  hand, and the incoming player may place it anywhere on the playing surface.

On the Foul:

> **6. Fouls**
>
> The following actions are fouls at pool when included in the specific
>   rules of the game being played. If several fouls occur on one shot,
>   only the most serious one is enforced. If a foul is not called before
>   the next shot begins, the foul is assumed not to have happened.
>
> **6.1**
>
> Cue Ball Scratch or off the Table  If the cue ball is pocketed or driven off the table, the shot is a foul.

However, it depends what rules you play by, determined prior to the match start.

> When the cue ball is in hand, the shooter may place the cue ball
>   anywhere on the playing surfaceand may
>   continue to move the cue ball until he executes a shot. Players may use any part of the cue stick to
>   move the cue ball, including the tip, but not with a forward stroke
>   motion. In some games and for most break shots, placement of the cue
>   ball may be restricted to the area **behind the head string** depending on
>   the rules of the game, and then 6.10 Bad Cue Ball Placement and 6.11
>   Bad Play from Behind the Head String may apply.

For reference, behind the head string is also known as the kitchen.

[image]

I would recommend clarifying with your opponent which rules you want to play by prior to starting the game.  [I usually play any foul committed is ball in hand]

[Rules](http://www.wpa-pool.com/web/index.asp?id=116&pagetype=rules#1.5)

Answer (score 0):

As @ZeroStack points out it depends on the rules you are playing.  If you are playing [IPA Backball Rules](http://ipapool.com/wp-content/uploads/IPA-Blackball-Rules.pdf), you can have *cue ball in hand* anytime your opponent commits a foul.

Rule 4h states that when you have *cue ball in hand*, you must play anywhere behind the baulk line.